# If $N$ is nilpotent of index $n\geq 2$ but $N^{n-1}\neq 0$ then there's no $A$ such that $A^2=N$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $N\in M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ a nilpotent matrix of index $n\geq 2$. Prove: if $N^{n-1}\neq 0$ then there does not exist a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ such that $A^2=N$.

My attempt: suppose there is such a matrix. Then $A^{2n}=N^n=0$ and thus $A^n=0$ (by Cayley-Hamilton/minimal polynomial). But $A^{2n-2}=N^{n-1}\neq 0$ and this contradicts the fact that $A^n=0$ (because $2n-2\geq n$). Is it correct? (looks too simple)

Comment: Looks good. You can also deduce a contradiction by noticing that $A$ must be nilpotent and considering the possible indices of nilpotency of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is perfectly fine.  It's easy because the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is a strong result.